# Overlay two divs

Tags: html, css

How do I get two div areas over each other? On the following website I try to get the search field in center and over the slider:
http://informationen.lensbreak.com

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: relative;">
    <div sytle="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;">[rev_slider testslider]</div>
    <div sytle="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 2;">[search]</div>
</div>
```

The whole thing should stay responsive.

Comment: use 'style' instead of sytle

Answer (score 0):

As a rule you should not use inline-styling if you can avoid it - use classes instead. And below is a solution that will center the searchbox both horizontally and vertically over your slider.

```
/* This is for your search form */
#completeSearchForm {
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translate(0px, -50%);
}

/* This is for the div that contains the search form */
.your-modifier {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
(I added border for each div to help you see areas of divs.)

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: red 3px solid">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;  border: blue 2px solid ">[rev_slider testslider]</div>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%;  border: green 1px solid ">[search]</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want You can also use

```
<table>
```

instead of div it can be easier for You.